# post composition as a functor?

Tags: category-theory

For every arrow $f$, we have a post composition functor $f_\ast$. However, one often uses the equality $(gf)_\ast=g_\ast\circ f_\ast$. I was wondering, what's the actual definition of this functor $(-)_\ast$?

Comment: It is not clear of what functor you are talking about. Maybe the covariant hom-functor $\mathrm{Hom}(X, -)$?

Comment: That notation is commonly used to mean "push forward" - are you working with topological or geometric objects?

Comment: Or perhaps you mean, given $f:X\to Y$, the transformation of functors $f_*:\text{Hom}(-,X)\to \text{Hom}(-,Y)$?

Answer (score 1):

Given a category $C$ there is a functor $C\to\mathrm{Cat}$ that sends an object $c$ to the slice category $C/c$ and sends a morphism $f$ to the postcomposition functor $f_*$.